# Layout load before event isn't triggered

Tags: magento2, layout, event-observer

I have an event

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="redirect_pro_homepage" instance="Cpy\CheckUrl\Observer\RedirectVisitor" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In local env; this observer is called.

In my sandbox env this observer is called.

In my preproduction env, this observer is not called.Can't understand why.

Any explanation on what might cause this ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, I can't tell the real reason behind it but direct explanation was :

In config.php the module was shown as activated.

But for some reason for magento it was disable anyway.

So I just forced the activation in command line. Everything went good.